# how to redirect to new page based on time in jsp?

Tags: multithreading, jsp, servlets

I want to redirect to new jsp page based on time. For instance, an employee forgotten to logout his account even though there is a session expired option. Instead session expire can i use timer to redirect logout page?

Comment: why do you want it to be done separately , though you have an option . _pls make use instead of inventing_

Comment: For learning purpose...This will helpful for someone else. Do you have any idea.Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript `setTimeout` method.

```
$(document).ready({
setTimeout(function() {
    //code for session invalidate and redirect to login page
  }, 50000); // calls after 50 seconds

});
```

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped u.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go... one of the way to redirect new page. After 5 seconds this page will be redirected to logout page.

```
<script> 
var timeout = 5; //set time here 5sec
function timer(){ 
   if( --timeout > 0 ){ 
      document.forma.clock.value = timeout; 
      window.setTimeout( "timer()", 1000 ); 
   } 
   else{ 
     document.forma.clock.value = "Time over"; 
     ///disable submit-button etc 
   } 
   if(document.forma.clock.value=="Time over"){
     top.document.location.replace('logout.jsp'); //redirect page url
   }
}     
</script> 
<body> 
   <form  name="forma"> 
      <% String clock = null; %>     
      You will be logged out after:<input type="text" size='1' name="clock" value="<%=clock%>" style="border:1px solid white">seconds
     <script> 
        timer(); //calljs timer()
     </script> 
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```